# How is the Baron Power Play calculated?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the MSI Game G2 vs FW Caps managed to steal Nash. 
The Baron Power Play total was +5431g. How was this calculated?
I could imagine it to only count turrents and kills, but it seems to add / substract gold on the fly.
What influences this counter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just the total change in gold while Baron (Nash) buff was active.

A Baron Power Play of +5431g means that for the 3.5 minutes that G2 had the Hand of Baron buff, they earned 5431 more gold than FW in that time frame.

If the buff ends early, then the Baron Power Play ends there. Note that it's also possible for a Baron Power Play to be negative: if 4 members lose it and the opposing team proceeds to take several objectives before killing the last member, the opposing team would have come out ahead, and so the power play would have negative value. Of course, in this case, the production staff would probably not display the graphic :-)

---

I found [a comment by Riot SwampWTFox](https://web.archive.org/web/20200314173607/https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/esports/EranAQRT-what-does-baron-power-play-gold-mean), an Associate Producer for the NA LCS, that confirms this:

> It's the difference in gold a team gained or lost whilst having the baron buff. So for example; if Team A gets baron and the earns 4,000 gold, and during that time, Team B earns 2,000 gold, then the Baron Power Play will be +2,000 gold. On the other hand, if Team A gets baron, but then is immediately aced by the enemy team, and lose multiple turrets, you might very well have a Baron Power Play of negative value.

Comment: "Of course, in this case, the production staff would probably not display the graphic :-)" Why not? From a spectator perspective, a negative Baron power play is as relevant and exciting as a positive one; potentially more so, since a negative Baron power play occurs less frequently and indicates a more unexpected game state (such as the losing team stealing Baron then immediately getting wiped or the losing team getting a big team fight win while the winning team has Baron). I've definitely seen negative Baron power plays during the recent Worlds games. I'd assume that's all automated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to imply that you're not taking into account all gold sources.

### That is, **you're forgetting *farm***.

Those constant "additions/substractions on the fly" are nothing more that passive gold earning + farming.

First of all, the 300 gold every teammate earns are counted towards the "Baron play" or gold advantage accrued with baron. So if during the first 20 seconds of baron the team that got it pushes and gets X minions for about 600 gold, the total power play at 2:40 min left of baron would be +2100 Gold (1500+600). And so on, with kills, bounties, towers, and any source of gold.